# Mark overridden functions

Tags: c++, overriding, doxygen

Does a command exist, like `\deprecated`, but to mark overridden functions?

Java has an annotation `@override` for functions you have overridden. I would like to do the same in C++, so that I can to see the superclass functions I've overridden. At best, the documentation page should also show all class member functions, which are inherited, but not explicitly overridden with hyper-links to the superclass functions.

I know there is a way to copy the documentation from the superclass method. But I don't want to have the whole doc copied. I just want to know, that a function is inherited. The behavior should be similar to the deprecated option to mark those old functions with a bar.

Comment: There is an [`overload`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdoverload) command.

Comment: @Chris: overloading != overriding, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/429236/79455

Comment: @rve You're right, I obviously didn't read the question closely enough.

Answer (score 9):

Every overridden function automatically gets a notice it has been reimplemented. For example the overridden function in a derived class gets the notice "Reimplemented from MyBaseClass."

It also puts a notice in the documentation of the base class. There is mentions "Reimplemented in Test"

To show all functions, including the inherited functions, you can set [`INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_inline_inherited_memb) to `YES`. Then Doxygen copies the documentation of every inherited, but not overridden, function into the documentation of the derived class.

For example, when using this source:

```
class TestBase
{
    public:
        /**
         * Base class function.
         */
        virtual void function();

      /**
       * Another function.
       */
      virtual void another();
};

class Test: public TestBase
{        
    public:
        /**
         * Overridden function.
         */
        virtual void function();
};
```

And setting `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB` to `YES` will result in the following documentation for the `Derived` class: (With Doxygen 1.7.6)

> **Member Function Documentation**
>
> `virtual void TestBase::another   (       )    [virtual, inherited]`
>   Another function.
>
> `virtual void Test::function  (       )    [virtual]`
>   Derived.
>   Reimplemented from TestBase.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi rve, thanks that is a good tip, but not the whole solution for me. If I override my own functions, that's ok, but if I override e.g. a qt function, doxygen doesn't recognize that it is overriden. I also don't get the inherited block in brackets, but just a reimplemented in message. That's ok, but I wish, I could see the overriden status directly in the member list overview.

Comment: A bit late, but you can use tag files to let Doxygen know about classes documented elsewhere. If you have a tag file for QT, then (I think) it should mark functions inherited from QT. Never tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

Since **C++11** you can use the **override** specifier:

```
class A {
    virtual void jump() = 0;
    void talk() {}
};

class B: public A {
    void jump() const override {...} // Error: B:: jump does Not overrides A:: jump (A::Jump is not const...)
    void jump() override {...} // OK: B:: jump overrides A:: jump
    void talk() override {...} // Error: A::talk is not virtual
};
```

Original Example and official doc: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override