# Switching between inherited and non-inherited view of methods in API docs?

Tags: c++, doxygen

We have a C++ library, and we use Doxygen for API documentation. The documentation is built with Doxygen 1.8.10.

I was talking with one of our users, and they want the API docs to only show the non-inherited methods of a class (and not the inherited methods that were *not* overridden). Here was the request:

> One of the issues is just doxygen.  I'm obviously a Qt user,  and the Qt
>   docs have always been good.  The thing over doxygen is that Qt docs only
>   show implemented and virtual functions for  a class.  This allows me to see
>   what a class provides above its inherited classes.  So if i want to know the
>   difference between FileSink and StringSink,  it'll be more obvious.  Look at
>   doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html (rough equivalent to a filter) and then
>   compare descendant classes QFile and QNetworkReply.  Whereas the doxygen
>   just lists everything, the Qt docs tell me just what is special about that
>   class.  This might be just one setting that would go a long way.

How do I tell Doxygen to offer the user of a choice in the way it displays a class' documentation? That is, it should allow a user to view all of the class' methods (inherited and non-inherited) or just the methods added by the class (i.e., overridden and non-inherited).

Is it even possible to change views with Doxygen?

Thanks in advance.

---

The only thing I can find in `Doxygen` is the following, but its a build-time setting. Its not a view-time choice a user can make:

```
# If the INHERIT_DOCS tag is set to YES then an undocumented member inherits the
# documentation from any documented member that it re-implements.
# The default value is: YES.

INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
```

---

The question looks similar to [Mark overridden functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10562511/608639) and friends. But we are looking for a "toggle" view-time option. That is, we want to give the user a choice at view-time, and not force something on them at build-time.