# Can operator<< in derived class call another operator<< in base class in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, derived-class

In my code, `Manager` is derived from `Employee` and each of them have an `operator<<` override.

```
class Employee{
protected:
    int salary;
    int rank;
public:
    int getSalary()const{return salary;}
    int getRank()const{return rank;}
    Employee(int s, int r):salary(s), rank(r){};
};
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Employee& e){
    out << "Salary: " << e.getSalary() << " Rank: " << e.getRank() << endl;
    return out;
}

class Manager: public Employee{
public:
    Manager(int s, int r): Employee(s, r){};
};
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Manager& m){   
    out << "Manager: ";
    cout << (Employee)m << endl;  //can not compile, how to call function of Employee?
    return out;
}
```

I hoped `cout << (Employee)m << endl;` would call `ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Employee& e)`, but it failed.

Comment: what is the compile error?

Comment: You are slicing (at least the code is trying to; look it up). You need to write `static_cast<Employee&>(m)` instead of `(Employee)m`.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth it should fail to compile because a temporary `Employee` can't bind to `Employee&`. If you are using MSVC then it has an incredibly stupid extension that allows this dangerous behaviour.

Comment: `(Employee)m` will result in a copy of the Employee part of m which is a temporary. I don't think it can match `Employee & e` parameter of your overload.

Comment: @Simple: Luckily g++ punishes you hard for that. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast to a reference instead of a copy:

```
cout << (Employee&)m << endl;  //can not compile, how to call function of Employee?
```

Also note the ostream operator is in no way member of the class(it seems you are confused about that from the title of the question).

Answer (score 4):

The usual way of doing this is to have (a possibly `private` or `protected`) virtual `print` (or any other suitable name) function in the base class that derived classes can override.

You only provide general `operator<<` for a reference to the base class and call `print` inside it. The overriding `print` functions can call the base's `print`, if need be.

Comment: His `operator<<` are actually external to the classes entirely.

Comment: @ZacHowland I don't see a problem with that. You can declare them `friend`, as usual for stream operators.

Comment: @jrok. Sorry. I just don't think this is an answer to the actual OP's problem. Even though what you said is correct.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems a shame to introduce polymorphism when the problem is solvable with static types.

Comment: @jrok I wasn't stating it as a problem, just as a note (the first sentence of your second paragraph kind of implies it as a class member - which it can be, but is not in this particular case).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ironically, it actually appears that he has the static type solution already (unless I'm misreading the purpose of the `rank` member) ... but even if I am, a simple boolean value in the `Employee` class solves that as well.

Comment: @ZacHowland I see, I reworded it a little.

Answer (score 4):

Change `cout << (Employee)m << endl;` to `cout << (Employee&)m << endl;`.

The explanation of the error message is this:

When you attempt the cast `(Employee)m`, you are creating a temporary.  The `operator<<` overload takes a *reference*.  You cannot take a reference to a temporary.

Since you really just want it to print it's own data (not make a copy of itself), you cast the reference you have to the reference of the type you need (it's base class).

As jrok pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19710761/529761), you can also accomplish this by providing a virtual function to print the data.  That would be a simpler approach as it would not require you to overload `operator<<` for every derived class.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That is what I said.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry... **I** missed something

Answer (score 1):

Your overload:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Employee& e)
```

only works for references to `Employee` objects, so it won't work on non-reference values (like the result of a cast).

Normally, the prototype would be:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Employee& e)
```

which also provides the reassurance that printing an Employee doesn't mutate it. If you change that, things should work just fine. (`ostream&` *does* have to be a reference, not a const reference, because the `ostream` is mutated by the print operation.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems which combined make your compilation to fail.

(1) This declaration and definition:

```
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Employee& e){
        out << "Salary: " << e.getSalary() << " Rank: " << e.getRank() << endl;
        return out;
    }
```

Despite you don't change `e`, you take it reference to non-`const`. This forbids you calling this operator on an rvalue.

(2) This line

```
cout << (Employee)m << endl;
```

As said by others you are slicing `m`. In addition, the cast `(Employee) m` returns a temporary `Employee` which is an rvalue.

In summary, the cast `(Employee)m` yields an rvalue which cannot bind to `e`.

You can fix either one or the other to make your code compiler but it's better to fix both problems to make your code more robust:

```
// ...
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Employee& e) {
// ...

// ...
cout << static_cast<Employee&>(m) << endl;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you overload a global function. This is another concept than overriding. see [Override and overload in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/429125/2932052)

Next, your cast is wrong. This should do:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Manager& m){   
    out << "Manager: ";
    cout << static_cast<Employee&>(m) << endl;  //can not compile, [...]?
   return out;
}
```

...if you really want to overload the global `<<` operator.