# What are the differences between overriding virtual functions and hiding non-virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding, method-hiding

Given the following code fragment, what are the differences in the function calls? What is function hiding? What is function overriding? How do they relate to function overloads? What is the difference between the two? I couldn't find a good description of these in one place, so I'm asking here so I can consolidate the information.

```
class Parent {
  public:
    void doA() { cout << "doA in Parent" << endl; }
    virtual void doB() { cout << "doB in Parent" << endl; }
};

class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    void doA() { cout << "doA in Child" << endl; }
    void doB() { cout << "doB in Child" << endl; }
};

Parent* p1 = new Parent();
Parent* p2 = new Child();
Child* cp = new Child();

void testStuff() {
  p1->doA();
  p2->doA();
  cp->doA();

  p1->doB();
  p2->doB();
  cp->doB();
}
```

Comment: @kerrek-sb I can't find an explanation online (which is where I usually look, and others probably do too) that _compares_ these. They have explanations of one or the other, but not both, and I wanted to put something online that would be easy to reference. Thanks for the catch on the access specifiers.

Comment: @karadoc No, it's just something that I found. The explanations I've found explain one or the other, but don't give a comparison of them, and that's what I'm trying for.

Comment: @karadoc, FWIW, I was about to post this same question and no, it is not for a homework assignment. I am long out of college. Thanks for positing this Jed, although unfortunately I still don't understand what the virtual keyword is for, unless you're trying to make an abstract base class with pure virtual functions. Apart from that, I fail to see what "virtual" does from a practical standpoint, since I can just hide the function.

Comment: Nothing wrong if this sounds like a homework assignment. I not doing any homework, this exact question came into my head, I googled it, and found this great resource. I imagine many others are in the same situation. It is incredibly usefully to find the answer immediately.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### What is function hiding?

... is a form of name hiding. A simple example:

```
void foo(int);
namespace X
{
    void foo();
    
    void bar()
    {
        foo(42); // will not find `::foo`
        // because `X::foo` hides it
    }
}
```

This also applies to the name lookup in a base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void foo(int);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo();
    void bar()
    {
        foo(42); // will not find `Base::foo`
        // because `Derived::foo` hides it
    }
};
```

---

#### What is function overriding?

This is linked to the concept of virtual functions. [class.virtual]/2

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* `Base::vf`.

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual void vf(int) const &&;
    virtual void vf2(int);
    virtual Base* vf3(int);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public: // accessibility doesn't matter!
    void vf(int) const &&; // overrides `Base::vf(int) const &&`
    void vf2(/*int*/);     // does NOT override `Base::vf2`
    Derived* vf3(int);     // DOES override `Base::vf3` (covariant return type)
};
```

The final overrider becomes relevant when calling a virtual function: [class.virtual]/2

> A virtual member function `C::vf` of a class object `S` is a final overrider unless the most derived class of which `S` is a base class subobject (if any) declares or inherits another member function that overrides `vf`.

I.e. if you have an object of type `S`, the final overrider is the first overrider you see when traversing the class hierarchy of `S` back to its base classes. The important point is that the *dynamic type* of the function-call expression is used in order to determine the final overrider:

```
Base* p = new Derived;
p -> vf(42);    // dynamic type of `*p` is `Derived`

Base& b = *p;
b  . vf(42);    // dynamic type of `b` is `Derived`
```

---

#### What is the difference between overriding and hiding?

Essentially, the functions in the base class are always hidden by functions of the same name in a derived class; no matter if the function in the derived class overrides a base class' virtual function or not:

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual void vf(int);
    virtual void vf2(int);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void vf();     // doesn't override, but hides `Base::vf(int)`
    void vf2(int); // overrides and hides `Base::vf2(int)`
};
```

To find a function name, the static type of an expression is used:

```
Derived d;
d.vf(42);   // `vf` is found as `Derived::vf()`, this call is ill-formed
            // (too many arguments)
```

---

#### How do they relate to function overloads?

As "function hiding" is a form of name hiding, all overloads are affected if the name of a function is hidden:

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual void vf(int);
    virtual void vf(double);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void vf();     // hides `Base::vf(int)` and `Base::vf(double)`
};
```

For function overriding, only the function in the base class with the same arguments will be overriden; you can of course overload a virtual function:

```
class Base
{
private:
    virtual void vf(int);
    virtual void vf(double);
    void vf(char);  // will be hidden by overrides in a derived class
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void vf(int);    // overrides `Base::vf(int)`
    void vf(double); // overrides `Base::vf(double)`
};
```

Comment: Thanks! You explained this more cleanly and clearly than I did in my own answer.

Comment: @JedSchaaf I did *not* include the return type in the comments *on purpose*: Only the name is relevant for name hiding, and only the name plus the parameters are relevant for overriding. The return type can only make an override illegal, if it's not identical or covariant to the return type of the overridden function.

Comment: On that same line, though, you have that vf2(int) overrides and hides vf(int). An edit has to have at least 6 characters, so I added something that I thought might be irrelevant. Sorry for not being clear. :/

Comment: @JedSchaaf Oh, thanks! That's actually a typo. Yeah.. the editing system of SO discourages (or shall discourage) these kind of small edits, as every edit has to be reviewed by several people. See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204155) on [meta].

Comment: It's also worth noting that if a non-virtual method `Base::foo()` calls a virtual method `Base::vf()` in the base class, then calling `foo()` from a derived class will trigger the overriding method `Derived::vf()`, and not the original `Base::vf()`.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between calling a *virtual* member function and calling a *non-virtual* member function is that, by definition, in the former case the target function is chosen in accordance with the *dynamic* type of the object expression used in the call, while in the latter case the *static* type is used.

That's all there is to it. Your example clearly illustrates this difference by `p2->doA()` and `p2->doB()` calls. Static type of `*p2` expression is `Parent`, while dynamic type of the same expression is `Child`. This is why `p2->doA()` calls `Parent::doA` and `p2->doB()` calls `Child::doB`.

In contexts in which that difference matters, name hiding does not come into the picture at all.

Comment: Thanks, the static dynamic piece was what I was looking for; makes sense. So function hiding is better in terms of speed, whenever it can be used, but if the base class type is being used that typically won't be the case.

Comment: The first paragraph sums up any possible answer and any 100 examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We'll start with the easy ones.

`p1` is a `Parent` pointer, so it will always call `Parent`'s member functions.

`cp` is a pointer to `Child`, so it will always call `Child`'s member functions.

Now the more difficult one. `p2` is a `Parent` pointer, but it is pointing to an object of type `Child`, so it will call `Child`'s functions whenever the matching `Parent` function is virtual or the function only exists within `Child` and not in `Parent`. In other words, `Child` hides `Parent::doA()` with its own `doA()`, but it overrides `Parent::doB()`. Function hiding is sometimes considered a form of function overloading, because a function with the same name is given a different implementation. Because the hiding function is in a different class than the hidden function, it does have a different signature, which makes it clear which to use.

The output for `testStuff()` will be

```
doA in Parent
doA in Parent
doA in Child
doB in Parent
doB in Child
doB in Child
```

In any case, `Parent::doA()` and `Parent::doB()` can be called within `Child` using name resolution, regardless of the function's "virtual-ness". The function

```
void Child::doX() {
  doA();
  doB();
  Parent::doA();
  Parent::doB();
  cout << "doX in Child" << endl;
}
```

demonstrates this when called by `cp->doX()` by outputting

```
doA in Child
doB in Child
doA in Parent
doB in Parent
doX in Child
```

Additionally, `cp->Parent::doA()` will call `Parent`'s version of `doA()`.

`p2` cannot refer to `doX()` because it is a `Parent*`, and `Parent` doesn't know about anything in `Child`. However, `p2` can be casted to a `Child*`, since it was initialized as one, and then it can be used to call `doX()`.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson Probably because it's the same guy who asked the question. So it looks like he just asked the question to get some reputation points rather than to actually learn something.

Comment: Why do you assume I didn't learn this? I hadn't looked at these topics for a while, so I decided to look it up. When I couldn't quickly find exactly what I was looking for, I decided to add it here as a reference for others who might have similar questions. Do you not like that I answered my own question? The question submission has the option of adding an answer immediately, to "share your knowledge, Q&A style."

Answer (score 2):

A much easier example that differs b/w all of them.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual int fcn();
};

class D1 : public Base {
public:  
    // D1 inherits the definition of Base::fcn()
    int fcn(int);  // parameter list differs from fcn in Base
    virtual void f2(); // new virtual function that does not exist in Base
};

class D2 : public D1 {
public:
    int fcn(int); // nonvirtual function hides D1::fcn(int)
    int fcn();  // overrides virtual fcn from Base
    void f2();  // overrides virtual f2 from D1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code you're writen in the question essentially gives the answer when you run it.

Calling a non-virtual function will use the function from the same class as the pointer type, regardless of whether the object was actually created as some other derived type. Whereas calling a virtual function will use the function from the original allocated object type, regardless of what kind of pointer you're using.

So your program's output in this case will be:

```
doA in Parent
doA in Parent
doA in Child
doB in Parent
doB in Child
doB in Child
```