# Why does inheritance behave differently in Java and C++ with superclasses calling (or not) subclasses' methods?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

I have written - what seemed to be - exactly the same example of inheritance both in Java and C++. I am really amazed to see the different outputs of these programs. Let me share both code snippets and the corresponding outputs.

---

**C++ Code:**

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    void sleep() {
        cout << "A.Sleep" << endl;
        eat();
    }
    void eat() {cout << "A.Eat" << endl;}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    void sleep() {
        A::sleep();
        cout << "B.Sleep " <<endl;
        this->eat();
    }
    void eat() {
        cout << "B.Eat" << endl;
        run();
    }
    void run() {
        A::sleep();
        cout << "B.run" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B *b = new B();
    b->sleep();
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
A.Sleep
A.Eat
B.Sleep
B.Eat
A.Sleep
A.Eat
B.run

executed successfully...
```

---

**Java Code:**

```
class A
{
    A() {}
    void sleep() {
        System.out.println("A.Sleep");
        this.eat();
    }
    void eat() { System.out.println("A.Eat");}
};

class B extends A
{
    B() {}
    @Override
    void sleep() {
        super.sleep();
        System.out.println("B.Sleep");
        this.eat();
    }
    @Override
    void eat() {
        System.out.println("B.Eat");
        run();
    }
    void run() {
        super.sleep();
        System.out.println("B.Run");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
A.Sleep
B.Eat
A.Sleep
B.Eat
A.Sleep
......
......
......
(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError)
```

---

I don't know why these two examples of inheritance behave differently. Shouldn't it work similarly?

**What is the explanation for this scenario?**

Comment: In Java all methods are virtual (i.e. subject to overriding). In C++ they are not. If you give a subclass a method with the same name as a non-virtual method in the base class, they're just two similarly named methods.

Comment: I would change the title/question to something like "**What** is the difference between C++ and Java inheritance in this case?", because the **why?** is simply because c++ and java are two different languages

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Comment: Why wouldn't it be different? Making parallels between the two unrelated languages is often counter-productive.

Comment: Because methods in Java are [dynamic bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding) by default.

Comment: It's called method overriding here is a useful link they explain it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/

Comment: Try `void sleep() override {...` in the C++ code and see what the compiler thinks about it.

Comment: "I have written exactly same example of inheritance both in Java and C++" - no you haven't. You tried to get as close to the same syntax as you could (and didn't go far enough with the override keyword).

Comment: @Mat I am sure he is aware that it isn't *exactly* the same, as he himself knows the output is different. Those words where chosen to make the paradox obvious he stumbled across.

Comment: @khelwood while it would seem that a duplicate likely exists for this question, that link does not contain an appropriate duplicate target.

Comment: Why *shouldn't* they behave differently? They are two different languages.

Comment: One explanation is still vague to me....... "Why this java program ends up with ...StackOverflowError ??"

Comment: Because java program ends up falling into an infinite recursion, `sleep()->eat()->sleep()->eat()`. Eventually running outof stack memory. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your C++ example you are [hiding](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/name_hiding.htm) the base methods, but you don't override them. So they are actually different methods which just happen to have the same name. If you are calling

```
A* a = new B();
a->sleep();
```

it will actually print `"A.Sleep"`. If you want to override a method, you need to declare it [`virtual`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr139.htm) in the Base class (automatically making it virtual in all sub classes too). You can read more about function hiding vs overriding in C++ in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737267/4298200).

In your Java example you actually override the methods, so they are the same method. One taking the place of the old. You can think of it this way: all Java functions are secretly marked as `virtual`, meaning they can be overridden. If you want a method to not be overridable in Java, you must declare it [`final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).

Comment: ` final`  does have the same meaning in C++, BTW.

Comment: @MSalters true, but this is only necessary when the base class has already defined that method as virtual.

Answer (score 6):

Note: be careful, every language as its own way of *thinking*. There is a lot of ways to interpret/implement OO. Even if C++ and Java looks similar, they are far from similar.

In both languages, the compiler verifies **at compile-time** if you can call a method, by examining the class (and the one inherited from the current one, etc) for a method of the right signature and visibility. What makes things different is the way the call is really emitted.

**C++**:

**In the case of non-virtual methods** the method called is fully determined at **compile-time**. This is why even if the object is of class `B`, when it is executing `A::sleep` the call to `eat` is resolved as a call to `A::eat` (`eat` is not virtual then compiler calls `A::eat` because you are in level `A`). In `B::sleep()` the call to `this->eat()` is resolved as a call to `B.eat()` because at that place `this` is of type `B`. You can't go down to the inheritance hierarchy (call to `eat` in class `A` will never call an `eat` method in a class below).

Be aware that things are different in the case of virtual methods (it is more similar to the Java case while being different).

**Java**:

In Java, the method called is determined at **run-time**, and is the one that is the most related to the object instance. So when in `A.sleep` the call to `eat` will be a call related to the type of the current object, that means of the type `B` (because the current object is of type `B`) then `B.eat` will be called.

You then have a stack overflow because, as you are playing with an object of type `B` a call to `B.sleep()` will call `A.sleep()`, which will call `B.eat()`, which in turn will call `B.run()` which will call `A.sleep()`, etc in a never ending loop.