# Difference between using non-virtual base class functions versus derived class non-implemented virtual functions

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, name-hiding

This question is slightly related to [What are the differences between overriding virtual functions and hiding non-virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19736281/3672674), but I'm not asking about the technical details, rather about the usage of non-virtual and virtual functions.

Here's a little background. Let's say I have a base class A and two derived classes B and C

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A() {};
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "foo() called in A\n"; };
  virtual void bar() { std::cout << "bar() called from A\n"; };
  void xorp() { std::cout << "xorp() called from A\n"; };
  virtual ~A() {};
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B() {};
  virtual ~B() {};
  virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "foo() called in B\n"; };
  //virtual void bar() override not implemented in B, using A::bar();
};

class C : public A {
public:
  C() {};
  virtual ~C() {};
  virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "foo() called in C\n"; };
  //virtual bar() override not implemented in C, using A::bar();
};

int main() {
  A a{};
  B b{};
  C c{};

  a.foo(); //calls A::foo()
  a.bar(); //calls A::bar()
  a.xorp(); //calls non-virtual A::xorp()

  b.foo(); //calls virtual overridden function B::foo()
  b.bar(); //calls virtual non-overridden function A::bar()
  b.xorp(); //calls non-virtual A::xorp()

  c.foo(); //calls virtual overridden function C::foo()
  c.bar(); //calls virtual non-overridden function A::bar()
  c.xorp(); //calls non-virtual A::xorp()

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs, as expected, the following:

```
foo() called in A
bar() called from A
xorp() called from A
foo() called in B
bar() called from A
xorp() called from A
foo() called in C
bar() called from A
xorp() called from A
```

If I leave the virtual function bar() unimplemented in the derived classes, any call to bar() in the derived classes B and C gets resolved to A::bar(). xorp(), which is a non-virtual function, can also be called from the derived classes as either b.xorp() or b.A::xorp().

If I were to implement a xorp() in B, for example, it would effectively hide the A::xorp() and a call to b.xorp() would actually be a call to b.B::xorp().

Which brings me to my question, using the example above. Let's say I have a helper function that the derived classes need for their implementation.

**Is there a difference between having the helper function be a non-virtual member function (like xorp()), versus the helper function being a virtual function that the derived classes do not override (bar())**?

Reading through this presentation on class object layout and VTABLEs (https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~asharf/SPL/Inheritance.pptx, slides 28-35) I could not really spot a difference, since both non-virtual and non-overridden virtual functions point to the same place (i.e the function in the base class)

Could anyone give me an example where these two approaches would produce different results, or if there is a caveat that I have not spotted?

Comment: No difference.  But a derived class *might* override the function.  The usual caveat is that you don't know when it happens, who did it and why he chose to do so.  And can break your class doing it.  These are high risk factors that you have to think through when you design.  Hard to do correctly.  Luckily there is a very simple solution, declare the class `final`.  That might produce a phone call some time in the future, but it is one that eliminates all those risks.

Comment: You don't use **virtual inheritance** here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in your example is that you aren't using polymorphism. You operate on all the objects directly. You won't notice anything related to overriding, because none of the calls *need* to be resolved dynamically. And if the call is not resolved dynamically, there is absolutely no difference between virtual functions and non-virtual ones. To see the difference, use a helper free function:

```
void baz(A& a) {
  a.foo();
  a.bar();
  a.xorp();
}

int main() {
  // As before
  baz(a);
  baz(b);
  baz(c);
}
```

Now you should be able to see a noticeable difference in how the calls to `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are resolved. In particular...

> If I were to implement a xorp() in B, for example, it would effectively hide the A::xorp() and a call to b.xorp() would actually be a call to b.B::xorp().

... will no longer be true inside `baz`.

Comment: *"The flaw in your example"* - I think the example is specifically constructed to ask if the compiler will do anything differently when polymorphism is not used.

Comment: @HostileFork - I dunno, the OP asked *"Could anyone give me an example where these two approaches would produce different results, or if there is a caveat that I have not spotted?"*, which to me implies they are not sure about their example too. But if you think another answer applies, by all means, write it up. Answer diversity is SO's strength.

Comment: Thanks, the example with baz() definitely helped me a lot to understand what I was trying to ask better.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference between having the helper function be a non-virtual member function (like xorp()), versus the helper function being a virtual function that the derived classes do not override (bar())?

If you mark a method virtual but you never override it, it's behavior will be equivalent to if you'd never marked it virtual.  The relationship to other methods it calls in the object is not affected.

*That isn't to say there aren't still "differences".*

It certainly conveys a difference in intent to those reading the code.  If your xorp() method is not virtual--but relies on virtual methods to implement its behavior--then people will understand "xorpiness" as having certain fixed properties.  They would likely try to avoid a redefinition of xorp() in any derived classes, and know to only affect the xorpiness indirectly through defining the virtual methods it depends on.

Plus, the compiler can't always know if you're going to use a virtual override or not.  So it can't optimize out the extra code for virtual dispatch--even if you aren't "taking advantage" of it.  (Occasionally it can, like if you have a class you never derive from and don't export it...the virtual may just get dropped.)

And with exported classes you expect other people to use: just because *you* never overrode a method doesn't mean someone else won't.  Unless you use `final` and prevent derivation of your objects *(which isn't considered terribly friendly to do, unless you've got really good reasons)*.  So if you make something virtual, the ability is there, and once someone else adds an override then yes--there will be a difference at that point.