# Issue dispatching an overloaded operator to base in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, dispatch

Please forgive me if I fundamentally misunderstand something about dispatch in C++!

The code as pasted below works as intended.

However, if I uncomment/add the additional operator<< method in Derived (which should handle a different agrument type), C++ is then unable to resolve the previously-working dispatch "*this << something" (which, in the absence of that method, is successfully dispatched to Base as intended).

It says:

`main.cpp:25:15: Invalid operands to binary expression ('Derived' and 'Something')`

Please could someone explain to me why this happens?

Thanks in advance

(Mac OS Monterey 12.2.1, xCode 13.2.1)

```
#include <iostream>

class Something { };
class SomethingUnrelated { };

class Base {
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
    void operator<<(Something something) {
        method();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void method() { std::cout << "Derived::method() - Yay!" << std::endl; }
    void work(Something something) {
        *this << something;
    }
    // void operator<<(SomethingUnrelated somethingUnrelated) { }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Something something;
    Derived derived;
    derived.work(something);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function in the derived hides the base function. See: [What are the differences between overriding virtual functions and hiding non-virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736281/what-are-the-differences-between-overriding-virtual-functions-and-hiding-non-vir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in the parent class are hidden while building a lookup set for the [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup). You may bring the parent's operator to a child lookup set by `using` directive. I can't find the duplicated question, but I'm pretty sure the duplicated question exists.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void method() { std::cout << "Derived::method() - Yay!" << std::endl; }
    void work(Something something) {
        *this << something;
    }
    using Base::operator<<;
    void operator<<(SomethingUnrelated somethingUnrelated) { }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've learned something new!  (Sorry for the delayed response - been out of action with COVID since I posted).