# How to use virtual function in the base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual-functions

Consider the following two structures:

```
struct Potential{
    virtual double energy(int full_system, int particle_id)=0;

    double energy(int full_system){
        int n_particles=100;
        double E=0.0;
        for (int particle_id=0; particle_id<n_particles; particle_id++){
            E+=energy(full_system, particle_id);
        }
        return E;
    }
};


struct MorsePotential: Potential{
    //constructor
    MorsePotential (){}

    //implementing the virtual function
    double energy(int full_system, int particle_id){
        return 10.0;
    }
};
```

The first one, `Potential` has two functions, both called `energy`. The first is virtual and should be implemented in all child structures. The second should be inherited as is by all children. Note that the second calls the first one in the parent.

`MorsePotential` is a child of `Potential` and implements the virtual `energy` function from its parent. When using `MorsePotential`, however, I am getting a compilation error. The following code:

```
MorsePotential mpotential;
std::cout<<mpotential.energy(0,0)<<std::endl; //works
std::cout<<mpotential.energy(0)<<std::endl; //gives compiler error
```

gives the error:

```
inherit.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
inherit.cc:35:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘MorsePotential::energy(int)’
   35 |  std::cout<<mpotential.energy(0)<<std::endl;
      |                                ^
inherit.cc:25:9: note: candidate: ‘virtual double MorsePotential::energy(int, int)’
   25 |  double energy(int full_system, int particle_id){
      |         ^~~~~~
inherit.cc:25:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

I am confused because the first line compiles and I can call `mpotential.energy(0,0)`, i.e. the implementation of the virtual function. The child, however, is unable to find `mpotential.energy(0)`, i.e. the function implemented in its parent class.

I was wondering what causes this error? At first I thought that it may not be allowed to call virtual functions in the parent class, but defining `MorsePotential mpotential;` compiles so it seems to be able to instantiate the child.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What are the differences between overriding virtual functions and hiding non-virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736281/what-are-the-differences-between-overriding-virtual-functions-and-hiding-non-vir) (though I had to know the term 'hiding' to find it)

Comment: Declaration of `double energy(int, int)` in a child class *hides* the declaration of `double energy(int)` from its parent. You need to add a [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) in each derived class, or (much better IMHO) get rid of this dubious overload and use different names for different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) works. Name lookup does not consider the arguments. It only looks for the name of the called function. You call `energy`, `MorsePotential::energy` is found, name lookup stops before the base class scope is considered.

You can qualify the name, to select the method from the base, by calling `mpotential.Potential::energy(0);`.

Or you can pull the name from the base class to the derived class scope via a using declaration:

```
struct MorsePotential: Potential{

    using Potential::energy;   // <-------

    //implementing the virtual function
    double energy(int full_system, int particle_id){
        return 10.0;
    }
};
```

(You should not implement a constructor that does the same as the compiler generated one.)

Note that if you use actual polymorphism via a reference, the issue does not arise:

```
 void foo(Potential& p) {
      p.energy(42);    // OK, also with your code
 }
```