# Printing Function in C++ not working

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

Here is a code to print elements of an array. I am getting an error.Can anyone find out what is the problem with the code?

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int print_r(char arrName,int len){
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                    cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t";        
            }
}

 int main(){

int a[3];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;

print_r(a,3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you *think* the problem is? What does the compiler *say* is the problem? Please exhibit *some* effort toward solving this yourself. Come on.

Comment: Why are you asking us? What problem do you get when you run the code? There is one obvious problem I can see.

Comment: @Abhineet WOW I can't believe I missed that, thank you.

Comment: @JonnyHenly:: Happens buddy :-)

Comment: You still don't list what error you get. Have you *tried* to google the error you get? What information did that give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int print_r(char arrName,int len)
```

should be

```
void print_r(int *arrName,int len)
```

you are not retuning anything so it should be void, not int, and you declared your array as integer why do you use char?

Comment: Can I use it for both `int` and `char`,I think it is not possible I need another Function for `char array` like 
`void print_r(char *arrName,int len)`
Can I make one function for both???

Comment: other than overloading i am not aware of another way of using the same function for different arguments, have look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429125/override-and-overload-in-c

Comment: Use a template if you want to call the function with different types - `template<class Type> void print_r(const Type* arrName, std::size_t len)`

Answer (score 1):

It is an obvious error that you are passing `int*` to `char` argument in function. Hope this would help-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_r(int arrName[],int len){
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t";        
        }
}

int main(){

int a[3];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;

print_r(a,3);

return 0;
}
```

instead you can also define prototype as

```
void print_r(int *arrName, int len)
{
 //Function body lies here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change::

```
int print_r(char arrName,int len){
     for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
     cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t";        
    }
```

To

```
int print_r(int* arrName,int len){ // You are passing int array to print_r
     for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
     cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t"; 
     return 0 ; // int print_r( int*, int ) will expect an int return value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining your function **int** print_r, change the return type to **void** , that is,

```
int print_r(char arrName,int len){
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t";        
        }
}

//Instead use this
void print_r(char arrName,int len){
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                cout<<arrName[i]<<"\t";        
        }
}
```