# Calling virtual method in c++ gives access violation

Tags: c++, polymorphism, access-violation

I have a class named Renderable with one pure virtual method draw()

```
class Renderable : public QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
   virtual void draw() = 0;
}
```

And I have a class GeomObject that inherits from Renderable and also from Transformable (Transformable is a regular class, not virtual)

```
class GeomObject : public Renderable, public Transformable
```

GeomObject overloads draw() method. 
Also, I have a Scene class, in which I want cycle trough scene objects, and if they are Renderable, draw them. Each of them have isRenderable bool variable which is set to true. In this case, all of these objects are GeomObjects. SceneObject here is a regular class (not virtual)

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < this->sceneObjects.count(); i++ ) {
    SceneObject* obj = this->sceneObjects[i];
    if ( obj->isRenderable ) {          
        ( ( Renderable* )obj )->draw(); //access violation
    }
}
```

This is where I get access violation. But if I cast directly to GeomObject* and then call draw(), everything works fine.

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < this->sceneObjects.count(); i++ ) {
    SceneObject* obj = this->sceneObjects[i];
    if ( obj->isRenderable ) {          
        ( ( GeomObject* )obj )->draw(); // this works
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my class hierarchy:

```
class Renderable : public QOpenGLFunctions 
class SceneObject 
class Transformable : public SceneObject 
class GeomObject : public Renderable, public Transformable
```

Verifiable example of class hierarchy (it works, so the problem is probably somewhere else)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class QOpenGLFunctions
{};

class Renderable : public QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class SceneObject
{};

class Transformable : public SceneObject
{};

class GeomObject : public Renderable, public SceneObject
{
public:
    void draw(){
        cout << "Draw() is called"; 
    }
};

int main() {
    GeomObject * obj = new GeomObject();
    ((Renderable*)obj)->draw();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: The usage of a C-style cast almost certainly shuts up your compiler's warnings. Use the appropriate explicit C++ casts. In your case of multiple inheritance, use `dynamic_cast` and check that the returned pointer is valid before making a call on it

Comment: Don't use C-style casts, in particular when there is multiple inheritance involved. Use `dynamic_cast`, or `static_cast` if you're certain of the type.

Comment: There seems to be no connection between `SceneObject` class and `Renderable` class for cast of any kind to make sense.

Comment: Post a **complete example** that a reader can copy, paste and compile without modification.

Comment: @Ron It's casting a pointer, which would be fine if it were the proper kind of cast.

Comment: _GeomObject overloads draw() method_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/429236/8746007

Comment: SceneObject is a regular class, not virtual.

Comment: But what is the relationship of `SceneObject` to `GeomObject`, `Renderable` and/or `Transformable`?  Please show the class definition for `SceneObject`.

Comment: [Mcve] needed here

Comment: I'll try to make complete example a bit later. Here is my class hierarchy:

class Renderable : public QOpenGLFunctions
class SceneObject
class Transformable : public SceneObject
class GeomObject : public Renderable, public Transformable

Comment: @molbdnilo Indeed. I stand corrected.

Comment: Added a copy-pastable examble (edited the original post)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). And don't comment your own question, but edit it to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working example is not a valid example of the problem you describe. In your problem you try to cast a `SceneObject*` to a `Renderable*`. In the working example you are casting a `GeomObject*` to a `Renderable*`. `SceneObject` lies on a different branch in the inheritance chain compared to `Renderable` and there is no way I know of to directly cast an object to another branch.

If you absolutely want to use the `Renderable*` in your non-working example, you should be able to first cast to `GeomObject*` and then to `Renderable*`.

Also, as has been pointed out: Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead of C-style cast.