# Overwriting >> and << when having a class with an enum

Tags: c++

I have a class with an enum in it and I want to overwrite the >> and << operators, but I don't know how to do it while also modifying the istream and the ostream.

Piece.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Piece
{
public:
    enum class Color {
        red, black, yellow, white, undefined
    };

    Piece();
    Piece(uint8_t value, Color m_color);
    Piece(const Piece& toBeCopied);
    std::string getStringFromEnum(Color color) const;

private:
    uint8_t m_value;
    bool m_wasUsed;
    std::string m_name;
    Color m_color;
    
    void switchWasUsed();
    bool operator=(const Piece& toBeCompared);

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Piece& toBeReadInto);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& is, const Piece& toBeShown);
};
```

Piece.cpp

```
#include "Piece.h"

Piece::Piece():
    m_value(0),
    m_color(Color::undefined),
    m_wasUsed(0),
    m_name(std::to_string(m_value) + getStringFromEnum(m_color))
{
}

Piece::Piece(uint8_t value, Color color) : 
    m_value(0),
    m_color(color),
    m_wasUsed(0),
    m_name(std::to_string(m_value) + getStringFromEnum(m_color))
{
    if (value > 0 && value <= 15)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }
}

Piece::Piece(const Piece& toBeCopied):
    m_value(toBeCopied.m_value),
    m_name(toBeCopied.m_name),
    m_color(toBeCopied.m_color),
    m_wasUsed(toBeCopied.m_wasUsed)
{
}

std::string Piece::getStringFromEnum(Color color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case Color::red:
        return std::string("red");
    case Color::white:
        return std::string("white");
    case Color::black:
        return std::string("black");
    case Color::yellow:
        return std::string("yellow");
    case Color::undefined:
        return std::string("undefined");
    }

}

void Piece::switchWasUsed()
{
    m_wasUsed = !m_wasUsed;
}

bool Piece::operator=(const Piece& toBeCompared)
{
    return this->m_color == toBeCompared.m_color && this->m_value == toBeCompared.m_value;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Piece.h"

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Piece& toBeReadInto)
{
    is >> toBeReadInto.m_value >> toBeReadInto.m_color; //error
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Piece& toBeShown)
{
    os << toBeShown.m_value << toBeReadInto.m_color; //error
    /*option1, but now I don't really modify the ostream*/
    toBeShown.getStringFromEnum(toBeReadInto.m_color);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I might be able to do it using helper functions, like I did in operator<<, but I want to learn if there's any other way to do it so the i/o streams are modified.

So, is there any way to modify the istream/ostream without any helper function? Just like I would normally do with a non-enum field?

Comment: Just like you needed to provide operators `>>` and `<<` for your `class`, you also need to do the same thing with your `enum class`.

Comment: This question may need a [mre].  It seems that most of the code here is unrelated to your question about "overwriting >> and <<"

Comment: Side note *overwriting* should be *overriding*, but here you are not *overriding*, you are *overloading*. *Overriding* is when a derived class replaces a base class's virtual function. Read [Override and overload in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429125/override-and-overload-in-c) for details.